# How to enable build timing in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build, timing

I'd like to know how long my project's builds take, for example by displaying it in the build pane.
Is this option available somewhere in Xcode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Type this in the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES
```

Duration appears in the activity viewer after a build, alongside the "Succeeded" message.

If you are running the app, the status will be replaced by the running status before you can see the duration.

This replaces the entry that was used in older versions of Xcode:

> <s>defaults write com.apple.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES</s>

Xcode may need to be closed before you enter this command. Durations should appear at the bottom left of the project window.

Comment from an Xcode developer: "As with all undocumented user defaults, this is unsupported, assumed (but not guaranteed) accurate, and not assured to be effective in future versions."

Comment: I can confirm this works nicely. Close xcode. type in the above and restart xcode. In the bottom left of the main project window it states: Build succeeded [xxx sec]

Comment: Was this for XCode 4?  Screenshot of where it's supposed to appear?

Comment: I think this was for XCode 3. I totally can't remember leaving the comment, and found this page as I'm looking for the solution again.

Comment: This works for Xcode 6 as well. The build time is shown beneath the window title bar.

Comment: @bobobobo Screenshot of where the time appears in Xcode 6.1.1 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6KkYdls.png">

Comment: Still works in Xcode 6.4 and 7 beta 3. Shows in the Activity Viewer bar as pictured by @bobobobo.

Comment: Any way to get to print it, to a file?

Comment: Confirms this works for me in Xcode 7.1.1 (using the newer `com.apple.dt.Xcode`)

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES` worked for Xcode 7.2 (7C68) too.

Comment: It works in 7.3 [Screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/931655/14486595/c0c62e0a-0198-11e6-8ecf-8f5b1acf2634.png)

Comment: Sorry, can't find anything named "activity viewer" in Xcode menus, or window-panes, to see the results in - (Xcode 7.2). Where is this duration display?

Comment: If anyone else is wondering activity viewer is the window in the middle top of xcode where it shows what is currently being build and how far in the process it is.

Comment: Works in Xcode 12 too  They should start to document it 

Answer (score 34):

In Xcode 10, you are now able to see a great breakdown of the build times using their Timing Summary feature.

***Product->Perform Action->Build With Timing Summary***

This will show each of your target build times and the overall project build time. You can do a lot of analysis using this data and build times will depend on your hardware. Check out [Building Faster in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/408/) from WWDC 2018 if you care to learn more.

However, Xcode keeps track of all your builds by default and you can examine their times and logs by going to their Report Navigator.

[Build Logs within Report Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2G7K.png)

Comment: there is no way I can save the build log from XCode with timings. I can only see time in XCode output

Comment: @msk Yes, even for Xcode 14.2 the exported log doesn't include build time information.

Answer (score 11):

no, but you could use the command line. cd to your project directory and type

```
time xcodebuild
```

Answer (score 8):

After Xcode 10

- if you build from command-line, use `-showBuildTimingSummary`  to see the build time summary.

```
xcodebuild -showBuildTimingSummary
```

```
Build Timing Summary
CompileSwiftSources (1 task) | 5.434 seconds
PhaseScriptExecution (1 task) | 5.046 seconds
CompileAssetCatalog (1 task) | 2.788 seconds
CompileStoryboard (1 task) | 1.880 seconds CompileMetalFile (5 tasks) | 1.735 seconds
CopySwiftLibs (1 task) | 0.740 seconds
Ld (2 tasks) | 0.306 seconds
CodeSign (3 tasks) | 0.177 seconds
CompileC (1 task) | 0.170 seconds
MetalLink (2 tasks) | 0.046 seconds
Ditto (4 tasks) | 0.032 seconds
LinkStoryboards (1 task) | 0.023 seconds
```

- If you use Xcode, `Product->Perform Action->Build With Timing Summary`. And see building time summary in the Xcode building log.

Comment: Nowadays the right command line argument is `-showBuildTimingSummary`

Answer (score 4):

I solved it with `Run Script`s in `Build Phases`

I have added one Run Script at start point of the build:

`echo $(date +%s) > ../build_start_time`

and one at the end:

```
START=$(cat ../build_start_time)
END=$(date +%s)
echo $(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
```

Now i can see the time in Build Log -> All Messages

Comment: In Xcode 6.4, it won't let you drag a run script build phase before any of the "stock" build phases.  If you create a bunch of additional build phases, it will let you re-order those among themselves, but it appears all of the "stock" build phases must come first.  Have you found a way around this?